# How to extract "sunny" from below represented format?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

```
var email = req.body.emailId;

 connection.query('SELECT name FROM fun WHERE email = "' + email +'" ',function(err, result,fields) {


    console.log(result);

    });
```

The console displays "result" in the below format:

```
[{name:'sunny'}]
```

Can someone tell me how to display"sunny"?

Answer (score -1):

Sunny should be accessible with the following code

```
alert(result[0].name); //sunny!
```

As you can see, the JS object displayed is an array with one element, which is an object with one key (name).

So you simply index the array to the first value `result[0]` and then fetch that element's `name` value `result[0].name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that is true and  i should even look at those brackets too :p